# How to get text from <h3> without taking the span

Tags: go, goquery

I have the following function,

```
func getMosWantedInfo(doc *goquery.Document) {
    doc.Find("div.flex-align-center.bg-base-lightest.padding-1.margin-1").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

        // For each item found, get the title
        title := s.Find("h3").Text()
        reward := s.Find("span")
        // iamge := s.Find("imag")
        fmt.Println("###########")
        fmt.Printf("SUSPECT %d: Name: %s\n", i, title)
        fmt.Printf("SUSPECT %d REWARD:  %s\n", i, reward)
        fmt.Println("-----------")
    })

    // Handle what happens when doc.find doesnt find the article wanted
}
```

However, the title also retrieves the spans of the h3 tag, so how can I just get the text of h3?

Edit:

As an example:

```
<div>
    <h3>
        <span>Text to avoid</span>
        Text to collect
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a minimal, verifiable example?

Comment: Try `s.Find("h3").Contents().Not("span").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
 fmt.Println(s.Text())
})`